# Network Manager Applet always refuses to connect to another wifi

Tags: wireless, connection

I am running the latest lubuntu.

Network Manager Applet is generally always connected to my home wifi network. And it works just fine. In fact I never notice Network Manager Applet is there when connected to the home network, becasue it does such a fine job.

But whenever I connect to a different wifi, that is not the home network wifi, the Network Manager Applet icon just swirls and swirls and never connects. Very occasionally it will connect quickly to another network, but this is rare.

Lots of trying to connect and lots of waiting is necessary.

I have been using Lubuntu for very many years, have had many installations, and I think Network Manager Applet for re-connection to a 2nd or 3rd wifi has always been the weakest aspect of this marvelous OS.

Here are some of the things that I try, when connecting to another wifi network, that seem to make no difference to my capacity to connect:

- When I restart Network Manager Applet this seems to make no difference.
- Choosing the other wifi over and over again makes little or no difference
- Network Manager Applet rarely contains a full list of all wifi networks available
- Enabling and re-enabling wifi (right click on the icon) makes no difference.

Some questions that I have are

- Is there a text file I can flush somewhere to reset everything?
- Is there a way I can configure Network Manager Applet manually in text?
- Is there another Network Manager applet wifi I can use that is not Network Manager Applet?

All help and any ideas apreciated.

Comment: try restarting nm-applet : `killall nm-applet` then `nm-applet`

Comment: @kenn thanks. That's made a big difference. If you put it as the answer I can give the green tick.

Comment: @kenn I had been using `systemctl restart NetworkManager` but realised when I saw your above comment that would not necessarily kill all previously associated processes. Your suggestion seems to work well. Thank you.

Comment: I have set up @kenn's workaround with the following key board shortcut in Openbox/ Lubuntu in case it is of use to anyone. This makes for a useful and fast reset of the network manager applet. `<keybind key="w-c-a-r"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c 'killall nm-applet; sleep 1; nm-applet'</command></action></keybind>`

Comment: open `gnome-session-properties` then look for `Network` item in the list and check out the`command`  box, you can insert `nm-applet` to launch it every startup

Comment: @kenn I haven't used `gnome-session-properties` for a long time. Becasue I run everything from `autostart.sh`. I can't see that launching it at every start would be useful as It starts up anyway, probarly from `gnome-session-properties`. Did you mean to script killing it then sharting it again at start-up? I think that would be a good idea as I didn't always find a restart useful as I said previously.

Comment: `nm-applet` launches every startup since it's in `/etc/xdg/autostart/` so if you find `nm-applet.desktop` file and fix `exec` line, you won't need to kill and restart it.

Comment: @Kenn file `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` contains line `Exec=nm-applet`. What change are you suggesting?

Comment: it seems OK, I am confused now, why it doesn't work properly. Replace it with `dbus-launch nm-applet`, if it doesn't work revert the changes.

Comment: My bad, you use Openbox, I think it doesn't look in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, so check out  contents of `/etc/xdg/openbox/autostart`